# Как получить одну любую запись из таблицы, с условием что в связанной таблице не будет записи с определенным значением?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `order` и связанная с ней `task`.
Мне нужно получить одну любую запись `order` с условием что в связанной таблице `task` нет записи с определенным ID(например: 5) в поле `task`.`executor_id`.

**Структура и связи**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал следующий запрос:

```
SELECT `order`.* FROM `order` 
LEFT JOIN `task` ON `order`.`id` = `task`.`order_id` 
WHERE (`order`.`status`=10) AND
(`order`.`type`='10') AND
(`task`.`executor_id` != 5)
LIMIT 1
```

Он не сработал, похоже допустим ошибку:
а) Если записей в "task" нет вовсе: никакой записи не находится.
б) Если запись в "task" есть: находится запись, которая уже давалась текущему исполнителю(executor_id).

**Вопрос в рамках данной задачи:** Как получить одну любую запись с таблицы `order` с условием, что в связанной таблице `task` нет записи с определенным значением(например: 5) в поле `task`.`executor_id`?

**Общий вопрос:** Как получить одну любую запись из таблицы, с условием что в связанной таблице не будет записи с определенным значением? Может подзапрос использовать?

**Простой пример, если запутались:**

> У нас есть 2 заказа: "Собрать яблока", "Собрать груши" и исполнитель
> Петя. Петя уже взял заказ "Собрать яблока", и просит ещё один. Давать
> Пете повторно заказ "Собрать яблоки" не нужно - он ведь уже его взял,
> значит нужно дать заказ "Собрать груши".

Comment: *с условием что в связанной таблице task нет записи с определенным ID(например: 5)* Вообще нет? или связанной с возвращаемой записью?

Comment: Вообще нет. 

Если простыми словами, у нас есть 3 таблицы: order, executor, task. 
Когда executor начинает выполнять заказ - создаётся task. Так вот, нужно чтобы один и тот же executor НЕ МОГ взять один и тот же заказ. 

И вот данный запрос я создаю с целью проверять не нарушается ли данное поведение.

(извините за долгий ответ, были проблемы с доступом)

Comment: *нужно чтобы один и тот же executor НЕ МОГ взять один и тот же заказ.* Пфф... создайте уникальный индекс `task (order_id, executor_id)`, и всё...

Comment: Забегая наперед: Ваш ответ в топике помог!

В плане индексов: Предложения для решения интересное, спасибо. Извините, но в комментарии выше я неверно выразился, и данный кейс не подойдет, объясню почему:

Запросом мы выбираем любой заказ, в выполнении которого не участвовал executor. При введении индекса я решу проблему повторных взятий, но не решу проблему поиска таких заказов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понимаю задачу, то

```sql
SELECT `order`.* 
FROM `order` 
LEFT JOIN task ON `order`.id = task.order_id
              AND task.executor_id = 5
WHERE `order`.status = 10 
  AND `order`.type = 10
  AND task.order_id IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

либо

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `order` 
WHERE status = 10 
  AND type = 10
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM task
                   WHERE `order`.id = task.order_id 
                     AND task.executor_id = 5 )
LIMIT 1
```